# Adding custom attribute for java-script resource in ADF page

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an external javascript library which needs to be included in the adf page. But while adding the library I want few extra attributes added with the script tag when it appears in html. It is required for mentioning callBack functions from the script. I could not find a way to add these extra attribute using the resource tag.

I am using Oracle Jdeveloper 12.2.1.3 for development.
I have tried using  tag. But it has no effect.

Following is the code I used to add external JavaScript

```xml
<af:resource type="javascript" source="http://..."></af:resource>
```

This will appear in the page as follows

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://...">
</script>
```

Following is how I want it in the javascript with the custom attribute so that the callback will work.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://..."
      data-error="errorCallbackHandle" data-cancel="cancelCallbackHandle">
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is due to the tags `<af:resource>...</af:resource>`

```
<af:resource type="javascript" source="http://..."></af:resource>
```

Kindly use the normal tags for javascript as follows:
Drag and drop component >> "script (HTML.Common)" into your jsf "af:document" using Jdeveloper.
It will create the script as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
src="http://..." data-error="errorCallbackHandle" data-cancel="cancelCallbackHandle"
</script>
```